# date() function in PHP and its 2nd parameter

Tags: php, date, datetime

PHP [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) documentation says:

> **timestamp**
>   The optional timestamp parameter is an integer Unix timestamp that defaults to the current local time if a timestamp is not given. **In other words, it defaults to the value of time()**.

I'm using server located in Belgrade (timezone in php.ini is "Europe/Belgrade") which is UTC+2 currently:

```
echo date('F j, Y, H:i - e') // result => March 30, 2016, 18:22 - Europe/Belgrade
```

Now I would like to get UTC time. If we know that time() **always defaults to UTC** time and it's same on all servers, I should be able to do this to get UTC time:

```
echo date('F j, Y, H:i - e', time()); // result => March 30, 2016, 18:22 - Europe/Belgrade
```

but result is the same. I was supposed to get `March 30, 2016, 16:22 - UTC`. In docs it says:

> The optional timestamp parameter is an integer Unix timestamp that
>   defaults to the current local time if a timestamp **is not** given

but if it's given, it should default to what's given, isn't that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `date('F j, Y, H:i - e', time());`, `time()` is still resolving to your current server time which from your first code is `March 30, 2016, 18:22 - Europe/Belgrade`. Therefore, essentially, your code is still the same; as `date('F j, Y, H:i - e' [, $timestamp = time()])` is treated as `date('F j, Y, H:i - e', time());` since there is no second parameter. To get UTC time, I will suggest you use 
`echo gmdate('F j, Y, H:i - e'); //will output March 30, 2016, 16:22 - UTC`
rather

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, agreed with @KBJ answer or, you can set the timezone of wherever(Asia in your case) you want to get time and then get time.
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date= date('m-d-Y') ;